# XSLT 1.0 - Unknown type {} specified in xsi:type attribute

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I have a soap xml message that looks like -

```
 <soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <getFunctionResponse xmlns="urn:JadeWebServices/WebService/">
                <getResult xsi:type="WS_getResult">
                    <date>August 2018</date>
                    <ID>100964</ID>
                    <MoreContent>...</MoreContent>
                </getResult>
            </getFunctionResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to write an XSLT to get the content wrapped at the getResult level. The getResult tag name changes based on the service I call and I need to do different things based on the name.

However, it refers to an xsi:type that keeps failing validation. When I delete the xsi:type attribute everything seems to work. I cant seem to get around the validation - Any pointers?

=====================================
Edit: Based on comment

Here is the xsl I have so far

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name(soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*[1]) = 'getFunctionResponse'">
                <Payload>
                    <xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getFunctionResponse/getResult"/>
                </Payload>
                <!--Do some success response related transformation-->
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Error>
                    <xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getErrorResponse/getResult"/>
                </Error>
                <!--Do some Failure response related transformation-->
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to do different transformation logic based on the name of the node directly under soap:Body. There a 5 different "types" of responses i could receive, but for simplicity's sake I've shortened my XSLT to show two scenarios.

=================================================Edit: Exact Error message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Validation error: on line 4 column 76 of file:///c:/Users/Desktop/FULL_P~1.XML:
  XTTE1515: Unknown type {WS_getResult} specified in xsi:type attribute

    at com.exln.stylus.CSaxon8Driver.doProcessing(CSaxon8Driver.java:281)
    at com.exln.stylus.CProcessorDriver.process(CProcessorDriver.java:104)
Full_Payload.xml (4, 76)
Validation error: on line 4 column 76 of file:///c:/Users/Desktop/FULL_P~1.XML:   XTTE1515: Unknown type {WS_getResult} specified in xsi:type attribute
```

Comment: If the `getResult` element does not have a constant name, how can you refer to it? IOW, what is constant in the expected input? -- Also, what *validation* are you referring to? Why don't you post the XSLT you have so far, so we can fix it?

Comment: Hi Michael, Only the soap:Body element is constant and depending on how I make the request, the node directly under soap:Body will vary. I need to do different transformations for each of the scenarios. 
However, the getResult (or any variant of it) seems to have been typed to an xsi:type attribute that is defined in a schema I dont have visibility to and my xslt fails with the error message in the title. I think the processor is validating xsi:type attributes (happy to be corrected), that's the validation i'm referring to. Posted the xslt I have so far.

Comment: I don't get any error running your XSLT on your XML. Which processor are you using and what is the **exact** error message? -- P.S. The node directly under `soap:Body` is  `getFunctionResponse` - not `getResult` as stated in your question.

Comment: Hey Michael, Sorry I was away for a couple of days. I've added the exact error message in the question. I'm using Saxon 8 processor.